# How can I add a plot legend with variable value and text?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a list plot:

```
Print[ListPlot[Table[RAveList[ntempc], {ntempc, 2, 12}], Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> All,  PlotStyle -> Table[colors[[ntempc]], {ntempc, 2, 12}], 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[PointLegend[Table[colors[[ntempc]], {ntempc, 2, 12}], 
      Table[ntempc, {ntempc, 2, 12}], LegendMarkers -> Automatic], {Right, Top}], 
   Axes -> None, Frame -> True]];
```

My code is as above. I have 11 data list to plot with labelling "2-clusters" to "12-clusters", where number 2 or 12 is a variable, and "-clusters" is fixed text.

I explain a little more. `colors` is a list of color names(i.e. Red, Blue... ). `RAveList[ntempc]` is data sample to plot with labelling $n$-clusters.

Comment: wasato, I [formatted your code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for legibility but it would be useful if you were to provide a self-contained example that people could evaluate directly.  Also, you should not be using `Print` here apart from very specific applications.

Comment: If you have a `List`, `Table` is not necessary to extract a portion of the `List`, e.g., `Table[colors[[ntempc]], {ntempc, 2, 12}] === colors[[2 ;; 12]] === Rest[colors]`

Comment: If you were to omit the semicolon ( ; ) at the end of your code expression, you would not have wrap the `ListPlot` expression with `Print`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example has several problems, why people can not directly run it. For example you have not provided RAveList and you use it as it was a function. I assume it is an array, but the answer can be easily adjusted. Here is an example of the labels you wanted.

```
RAveList = RandomReal[1, {25, 5}];
selection = 2 ;; 15;
labels = Array[StringTemplate["``-clusters"], 25][[selection]]
ListPlot[RAveList[[selection]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[Automatic, labels], {Right, Top}], 
 Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit -**
In case you use older *Mathematica* than v10 replace 3rd line with

```
labels = Array[ToString[#] <> "-clusters" &, 25]
```

**Edit2 -**
Note that I parametrized shown subset of data using `selection` such that it would be easy to show different subsets on different plots. Code of the plot can be copy/pasted or turned into a function.

Note also, that you can use also `selection={2,5,11}` or `selection=Range[2,5]~Join~Range[10,15]`.

**Edit3 -** In order to give unique colors to all 14 lines and not to have legends on top of data making it unreadable, I change OPs code further

```
ListPlot[RAveList[[selection]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Join[ColorData[3, "ColorList"], ColorData[4, "ColorList"]], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[Automatic, labels], Right], 
 Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to having several errors. People can not run it directly because RAveList is result data. I guess ... labels = Array[StringTemplate["``-clusters"], 25][[selection]]... this part is important.

Comment: You can always give some dummy/random data which works for illustrating what you do.

I would study the whole example to learn about some neat practices I demonstrated, which allows one to write shorter and more clear code.

Comment: I find your code does not work for me, since StringTemplate is a new function after version 9. Others work well. Thanks.

Comment: @wasato I added an alternative.

Comment: Many thanks. It works well.

Comment: So use the tickmark button to "accept" the answer. This shows others, that you got your answer and no more help is needed.

Comment: The displayed legend is incomplete.

Comment: @karsten-7 This is actually a bug. As the list of colors is shorter than list of datasets `PointLegend` with `Automatic` only shows the labels with unique colors. I will make a bug report.

Comment: @Johu There is a simple workaround for that, just remove `Automatic`. Of course it doesn't make much sense to have the same color for multiple data sets. Maybe it's a feature.

Comment: @Karsten7. I agree, that it does not make a lot of sense and I did add more colors. See also the [bug discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121381/automatic-legend-does-not-include-all-datasets-in-case-of-short-list-of-colors).

Answer (score 5):

There are some things that bother me in Johu's solution, so I am offering this alternative, which seems both simpler and better to me. This works with versions of Mathematica older than V10.

```
RAveList = RandomReal[1, {11, 5}];
colors = ColorData[97];
labels = Row[{#, "-clusters"}] & /@ Range[2, 12];
ListPlot[Thread[Tooltip[RAveList, labels]],
  Joined -> True,
  DataRange -> {0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> colors,
  PlotLegends -> labels,
  Axes -> None,
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

I have added tooltips to each cluster plot because I believe, with so many plots in one view, it easier for the viewer to determine which is which with a tooltip than with a plot legend, especially if the viewer has vision problems that make colors hard to distinguish.

Comment: +1 as I agree, that cleanup and tooltips add value.

Comment: One can use `PlotLegends -> 
 LineLegend[labels, LegendLayout -> (Grid[#, Alignment -> Right] &)]` to have all `LineLegend`s in one column.

Comment: Why wrap labels with Row?

Comment: @Johu. I use `Row` because I find it to be the easiest way to create labels constructed from a mixture of expressions and strings.