# Automatic legend does not include all datasets in case of short list of colors

Tags: plotting, legending

The following code gives legend only for elements with unique color

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 10}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 2]],
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, Range[4]]]
```

or

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 10}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 2]],
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 2]], Range[4]]]
```

[image]

This simpler code provides expected result

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 10}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 2]],
 PlotLegends -> Range[4]]
```

[image]

I only came to this bug in a rare usage case. Usually one would not label datasets with a same color differently, but perhaps the bug effects some reasonable usage as well.

*Mathematica* V10.2,
Windows 8 64 bit

**Edit**
It actually has nothing to do with the `Plot` itself. Already this gives what I would call an unexpected behavior if you compare it to how `Plot` handles lack of unique colors.

```
LineLegend[ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 2]], Range[4]]
```

[image]

Comment: According to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html) (See under Scope -> Data), `LineLegend` remains unevaluated when first its parameter is `Automatic`. So, it is not a bug.

Comment: @SquareOne The section in the documentation refers to call of `LineLegend` outside `Plot`. In case it is wrapped in `Plot` it does get evaluated as I have illustrated. I also added two more examples (at the moment second and fourth image), which illustrate behavior also contradicting your interpretation.

Comment: I thought you meant a bug report for Wolfram Support. Did you send one there as well? I removed the bugs tag for the time being. Please check http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info for the general procedure for this special tag.

Comment: I did not report. I thought of discussing it before.

Comment: I think this may be considered a duplicate of [(66055)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66055/121).  Please take a look and tell me if you agree.

Comment: @Johu You are right for `Automatic`. But concerning your edit, actually in the same Scope/Data section of the docs, there is an example saying  that "`LineLegend` uses the shorter list of styles and labels" with this example:  `LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"}]` showing that `LineLegend`does not know to cycle colors.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I dont think it is a duplicate, `LineLegend` prevents `PlotStyle` from cycling colors. See my previous remark.

Comment: @SquareOne That seems at least very similar if not identical to what is happening with the example in your own question (66055).  The legend function makes only as many labels as there are styles.  What am I missing?

Comment: @SquareOne - I think that in the end that the two Q are about the same issue and it actually is specified behavior as cited. I agree, that it is not a bug and I should have read through the doc. However I still think it is silly and contradicting.

Comment: For your examples the easiest workaround is to simply drop `Automatic` or the color specifications and just use the form listed third in the documentation (only a list of labels, colors inherited from the plot).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The last example in the OP here: `ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 10}],Joined -> True,PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[;; 2]],PlotLegends -> Range[4]]` shows a correct behaviour of `PlotLegends`: it cycles the two colors in the `PlotStyle`, so it produces more labels than styles. I think the problem here is as I said that `LineLegend` prevents `PlotStyle` from cycling colors. Maybe that means (concerning the question 66055) that `PlotLegends->"Expressions"` or `PlotLegends->Automatic` uses `LineLegend` underneath ... ?

Comment: @SquareOne Sorry, I missed that distinction.  Thanks for your patience in pointing that out to me.  That seems a plausible explanation and raises the question in my mind at least of what the intended behavior actually was.

Comment: The reason that `Plot[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]` has four legends is because Plot cycles PlotStyle and PlotLegends is able to get four line style information out.

LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {1,2,3,4}] only has two legends is by design, as all the legend constructors don't cycle either color or text.

Comment: As for `LineLegend[Automatic, {1,2,3,4}]` in the plot producing only 2 legends, it is a genuine bug.