# changing line style from solid to dashed after an intersection

Tags: plotting, style

I used this link: [Plot that draws a dashed/solid curve depending on the y-value of the curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73389/plot-that-draws-a-dashed-solid-curve-depending-on-the-y-value-of-the-curve?rq=1) to help me start this. I have two lines. I want to change from solid to dashed after an intersection. The line with higher slope will have dashed line AFTER the intersection and the line with lower slope will have dashed line BEFORE the intersection. These two lines should be red and blue.

Here is what I have done so far...

```
In[289]:= y1 = 1.44; y2 = 27.9 - 16000 x;
intercept = x /. Solve[y1 == y2, x][[1]]

Out[290]= 0.00165375
```

The plot...

```
Plot[{y1, y2}, {x, .0014, .0019}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.0014, intercept}, {intercept, 0.0019}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}, MeshStyle -> None]
```

Here was the result...

[image]

Not sure how to fix this. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not wed to Mesh, it might be easier for you to accomplish what you're looking for with just having multiple functions, ala:

```
Plot[{ If[intercept > x, y1, None], If[intercept < x, y1, None],
    If[intercept > x, y2, None], If[intercept < x, y2, None]} // 
  Evaluate, {x, .0014, .0019}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Blue}, {Red}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[1/40], Gray, Point[{intercept, y1}]}]
```

yielding

[image]

(if you hate the dot get rid of the epilog)

---

**Update** riffing off your [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155636/51526) question re: Callouts, can combine as, e.g.

```
{f1, f2, f3, f4} = { If[intercept > x, y1, None], 
   If[intercept < x, y1, None],
    If[intercept > x, y2, None], If[intercept < x, y2, None]};

xRange = {.0014, .0019}; yRange = {-3, 8};

Plot[ {Callout[f1, "labelY1", {0.001775`, 3.64`}, {0.00174`, 1.754`}],
    f2, f3, 
   Callout[f4, "labelY2", {0.001525`, 5.7`}, {0.00156`, 3.3142`}]} // 
  Evaluate, Prepend[x][xRange], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Blue}, {Red}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
 PlotRange -> yRange, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: So here, LabelY1 and LabelY2 cannot have assigned values with units. Which, would go back to my original problem in that question

Comment: I just used the strings "LabelY1" and "LabelY2" to not overly import from the other question.  Can completely use e.g.: `Plot[ {Callout[f1, 
    formatQ["operational", q1], {0.001775, 3.64}, {0.00174,1.754}], f2, f3, 
   Callout[f4, formatQ["accelerated", q2], {0.001525, 5.7}, {0.00156, 
     3.3142}]} // Evaluate, Prepend[x][xRange], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Blue}, {Red}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
 PlotRange -> yRange, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]`  where `formatQ` provides formatting based upon data in q1 and q2.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean now. That works very well.

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[
 Plot[y1, {x, .0014, .0019},
  Mesh -> {{0.0014, intercept}, {intercept, 0.0019}},
  MeshShading -> {Blue, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}],

 Plot[y2, {x, .0014, .0019},
  Mesh -> {{0.0014, intercept}, {intercept, 0.0019}},
  MeshShading -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Red}],

 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, will try that. My actual plot has multiple things going on. I will see if this way interferes with the functions I would like to see on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

You have over specified your [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) option.  You only need: `Mesh -> {{intercept}}`. Unfortunately this solution does use show.

```
Show[
 Plot[#1, {x, .0014, .0019},
    PlotRange -> All,
    Mesh -> {{intercept}},
    MeshShading -> #2,
    MeshStyle -> None] & @@@
  {
   {y2, {Directive[Blue, Dashed], Blue}},
   {y1, {Red, Directive[Red, Dashed]}}
  }
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want the results to look like @eldo answer, but I do not want to use `Show`